# ejs scriptlet tags are not highlighted entirely

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

[scriptlet tags](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o798.png)

As shown in the pic, the end of the first pair of scriptlet tags remains white, however, my function works just fine. I am using vscode and have added the ejs-language-support extension and also configured the following settings

```
{
  ...,
  ...,
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "ejs": "html"
  }
}
```

Comment: What editor are you using? On which platform? Also, I think this kind of questions belong to https://superuser.com/

Comment: Hi sorry for not clarifying, I'm using vscode.

Comment: I think there is an open issue on the plugin's github: https://github.com/Digitalbrainstem/ejs-grammar/issues/40 refer to this attached picture: https://i.gyazo.com/deacfefeaf3d6d0c41d781c873dc3a43.png O.P. circled the `</ul>` tag, but if you look at his first `%>` he got different color too.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

1. Install `EJS language support` plugin
2. Now you have ejs support, highlighting, and snippets, but some tags like

```html
<? for( let item of array ) { ?>
(some data)
<? } ?>
```

are formatted incorrectly (at least with default html formatter).

3. To fix this, you can try set custom delimeter to '?' `ejs.delimeter = '?'`. Now you have correct indentation with  tags.
4. To use the snippets with our custom delimeter, you need to edit extension snippets (or add your own): install `Snippets Ranger` plugin, then find needed extension and edit its file. The `Snippets Ranger` is very handy tool.

I hope I helped somebody to setup VSCode for .ejs files